# Reading Excel File Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am having trouble receiving a certain output from code attached below. For some reason, the code I have is only outputting 3 of the 5 lines I want. I think the reason is that everything must be on same line. Anyway I can fix this. I also posted excel sheet to give you an idea of what I am talking about.[image: Excel Sheet] Also my output shown below for when year 2017 is picked.

```
     Select Year: 2017 
     ('126614', '126541', '125', '11')
     ('126615', '126523', '86', '32')
     ('126616', '126524', '59', '56')
```

- ```
   import csv
   with open('Data_2016.csv') as csvfile:
   reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
   year=raw_input("Select Year: ")

       for row in reader:
           Yearlink=row['Yearlink']
            year=row['Year']
                 if year==Yearlink:
                    print(row['From'], row['To'],row['Maxx'],row['Minn'])
  ```

Comment: Happening because the check u have added
    `if year==Yearlink:`
results in only 3 rows. (Only 3 rows with year as 2017)

Comment: There's seems to be only three entries of `2017` in your data?

Comment: Yes, that was done on purpose. more data needs to be included for 2017. Like for 2017, there are three data points, but I need to output 5 data points. Is there a way I can do this with the year labeled as 2017 for yearlinkup

Comment: To explain even more, in the year 2017, there are 3 Areas, but I need to output 5 stations in that area, and in each year, there a re a different amount of stationsn

Comment: @Mark Five data points of what? Do you mean certain columns/attributes? The code only prints three entries because your file only has three lines with the year `2017`.

Comment: five stations. My goal was to print out those 5 stations associated with the year `2017`. But I only have 3 areas with 2017. I can't add more areas. I thought if I set them equal to one another, it will everything. is there any way to do this. Like a match function or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you noticed, but you're overwriting your input `year` in row number 8.
Your code should actually return every row where `Yearlink` equals `year`.

Here's a corrected version.

```
import csv
with open('Data_2016.csv') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    year=raw_input("Select Year: ")

    for row in reader:
        Yearlink=row['Yearlink']
        if year==Yearlink:
            print(row['From'], row['To'],row['Maxx'],row['Minn'])
```

Comment: is there a way for the result to return the year not only in every row but wherever else  `2017` might show up for yearlink

Comment: it does not output anything for 2018

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question.

You input the year you are looking for and it returns the rows where `Yearlink` equals your input. 

If you input 2018, it should return all rows where the Yearlink equals 2018.